# CSS text-shadow property doesn't follow hierarchy with :visited pseudo-class

Tags: hover, inheritance, css, visited

I have a little problem with the visited pseudo-class and the text-shadow property in CSS.

Here is my code:

```
li.episode a{
display: block;
float: left;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
margin: 1px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #eeeaea;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
}

li.episode a:visited {
background-color: #23EE44;
text-shadow: none;
color: white;
}

li.episode a:hover {
background-color: #23EE44;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #10C72E;
color: white;
}
```

In fact what I would like to have is the visited link just the same as when hovered.

:Hover works fine on Chrome/Safari but the visited link keeps the first text-shadow property:

```
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
```

Instead of the one given below (I tried to use "none" in my code but doesn't seem to work..)

Thanks guys for your help !

Comment: try text-shadow: inherit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a very few css properties you can explicitly define for `:visited` due to [security issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector).

MDN defines the modifyable properties as (these may vary by browser, but text-shadow is certainly one that shouldn't work on any browser, at least modifying the size of it):

- color
- background-color
- border-color
- outline-color

And in addition you won't be able to define opacity or show/hide the links if the base `a` selector has done one of those things.

Comment: Your link is very interesting thank you. Then I'd like to deactivate the shadow I inherit (I indeed get the white text-shadow which makes the link look boold (white color + white shadow))

Comment: I've tried defining text-shadow in "li.episode a:link", in order to have "text-shadow: none" working for a:visited but I still get the white shadow of the a:link

Comment: @JohnThillaye You cannot modify how the `text-shadow` appears in `:visited` differently from how it appears in `a`. If you set the text-shadow for `a`, that's how it will appear for `:visited`, and if you leave it out from the `a`, you won't get it for the `:visited`